# BASH script cron scheduled for midnight - running every minute until 12:20am

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a Digital Ocean Ubuntu (18.04) LAMP server.

On it I have a simple bash script to create a backup directory and dump a site SQL file and a tar.gz of all the files.

**Crontab Entry**

```
# Backup files and database at midnight every night
0 0 * * * . /var/www/mysite.com/daily-backup.sh
```

There is only **one cron daemon** running on this server.

```
es@rental-link-production:/var/backups/rentallink$ ps aux | grep cron
es         606  0.0  0.0  14856  1100 pts/0    S+   10:32   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
root       959  0.0  0.0  31852  3160 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:02 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Yet overnight it must have ran almost every minute until 12:20am. There are no other cron scripts on this server.

```
es@mysite-production:/var/backups/mysite$ ls -lah
total 52K
drwxr-xr-x 13 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Apr 10 06:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:02 2019-04-09-1202
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:03 2019-04-09-1203
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:07 2019-04-09-1207
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:08 2019-04-09-1208
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:11 2019-04-09-1211
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:13 2019-04-09-1213
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:14 2019-04-09-1214
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:15 2019-04-09-1215
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:16 2019-04-09-1216
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:18 2019-04-09-1218
drwxrwxr-x  4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:20 2019-04-09-1220
```

Oddly enough on the staging server, which is an identical setup, it ran twice instead of just once at midnight - which is still once more than I was expecting.

```
es@mysite-staging:/var/backups/mysite$ ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Apr 10 06:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:01 2019-04-09-1201
drwxrwxr-x 4 es   es   4.0K Apr  9 12:20 2019-04-09-1220
```

I could almost expect to see this if the job failed and Linux tried to restart it... but it's a couple of mkdirs, a mysqldump call and a tar call. The CPU hasn't gone over 10% in the last 24 hours. It's not like it ran out of resources.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check /var/log/cron ? Also check /var/log/messages for clues about what may have happened.

Answer (score 0):

check these cases:
1-do other users call it?
2-does it call itself?
3-does it set in motion conditions for repetition?

for test add `whoami` at the end of the name.

for another test use `ps -A` to check if crond run more than one time.